# Unable to get latest version of Stringr, knitr, Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, stringr

R.version

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Error message:

```
Rendering R Markdown documents
Required package versions could not be found:
stringr 1.2.0 is required but 1.1.0 is available
knitr 1.18 is required but 1.14 is available
rmarkdown 1.10 is required but 1.1 is available
Check that getOption("repos") refers to a CRAN repository
that contains the needed package versions.
```

Operating system:

Windows 10 home premium

Issue and Question:

I have installed the newest edition of the free version of RStudio and seem to be having trouble rendering HTML documents from .Rmd files. It appears that I need a newer version of `stringr`, `knitr` and `rmarkdown` however when I try to `update.packages` it says, "Packages are up to date".  I check the repos and it has CRAN and CRANextra for repos and also tried to install packages via `install.packages`. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you update R? You're using a version that's more than 2 years old. And did you check that you're pointing correctly to CRAN like the error message says to do?

Comment: I downloaded what I thought was the newest version on the [https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/]. In my reponse, I outlined that I am pointing to CRAN and CRANextra which is the output of typing **getOption("repos")**.  Maybe that is all I get with the free version.

Comment: Just went to **Help** --> **check for update** and it says I am using the newest version of RStudio.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: R and RStudio aren't the same thing. Which packages you can run depend on your version of R, the language, not RStudio, which is a common IDE for development in R

Comment: My apologies, yes you are right, I will attempt to update R console. I thought I had done that but obviously didn't.

Comment: I was so caught up in trying to learn a new concept that I am unfamiliar with that, I didn't even notice the obvious.

Comment: In the end, you were right and please mark rewrite your response as the answer so I can close this off. I had multiple versions of R-console and path C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin was not being recognized as default.  Have removed the other versions and at least I have the version upto date.